# »Ausnahme dieses Grundsatzes« oder »Ausnahme zu diesem Grundsatz«?

Tags: grammar, preposition, grammatical-case

Heißt es

> die erste Ausnahme *dieses* Grundsatzes

oder

> die erste Ausnahme *zu diesem* Grundsatz

?

Comment: Kannst du das bitte in einen ganzen Satz betten und eventuell auch ein wenig Kontext mitliefern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> die erste Ausnahme dieses Grundsatzes

würde ich so lesen, dass der besagte Grundsatz selbst Ausnahmen beinhaltet, also z. B.:

> Unser Grundsatz lautet: »Luftballons für alle außer Rothaarige, Lamas und Buchhalter.« Die erste Ausnahme dieses Grundsatzes liegt darin begründet, dass […]

Vermutlich möchtest Du aber etwas anderes ausdrücken, und zwar dass ein zuvor formulierter Grundsatz eben nicht universell gilt:

> Wir raten im Allgemeinen dazu, Bananen vor Äpfeln zu transmogrifizieren. Die erste Ausnahme **von** diesem Grundsatz stellen Kochbananen dar, weil […]

Wie schon im Beispiel angedeutet, würde ich hier *Ausnahme von diesem Grundsatz* nutzen und auch generell als beste, wenn nicht gar einzig richtige, Lösung ansehen, da *ausnehmen* in dieser Bedeutung eben nur mit dieser Präposition funktioniert:

> Er war von dieser Verpflichtung ausgenommen.

aber nicht:

> *Er war dieser Verpflichtung ausgenommen.
>   *Er war zu dieser Verpflichtung ausgenommen.

Comment: Danke für die gute Erklärung!

Comment: Was heißt transmogrifizieren? Das Wort habe ich noch nie gehört und google liefert dazu nur Resultate von MMOs.

Comment: @raznagul: *Formwandeln,* aber ich hätte genausogut *verkasematuckeln* oder *diskombobulieren* nutzen können.

Answer (score 1):

Die zweite Version scheint einigermaßen akzeptabel zu sein, aber besser ist meiner Ansicht nach

> ...die erste Ausnahme **von** diesem Grundsatz.